# replace/migrate old mysql syntax with PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, replace, migrate

I'm learning how to access mysql db from php, and i saw a basic code (following) with mysql commands, however i realize that those syntaxis are old and it's better to use mysqli or PDO. I readed about it and i think that PDO is the way, so i appreciate any help on how to migrate this to PDO:

1) Connect to mysql database

```
 include 'DB.php';
 $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
 $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
```

2) Query database for data

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
 $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result
```

3) echo result as json

```
 echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Sounds like you ready to go, give it a try!

Comment: is it *real* code example or just artificial draft? if so - can you please post a real code example you want to translate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step

First

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
```

Second

```
$id  = 1;
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stm->execute(array($id));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Once you have result fetched as array you can encode as `json`

This comes from stackoverflow `PDO` tag wiki, you should have a [**look here**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I helps to understand.
However i found a simpler way to "equal" the example that i gave, without the $opt part.

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$stm = $pdo->query("SELECT * from $tableName");
$array = $stm->fetch();
echo json_encode($array);

Comment: @sergius you are welcome, don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems. To accept you just need to click on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't know. I always try "voting up" but systems doesn't let me do that because i'm a new user. I didn't know about that posibility! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found this to be almost exact equal to the classic mysql commands, now in PDO:

```
<code>
include 'DB.php';
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);
$stm = $pdo->query("SELECT * from $tableName");
$array = $stm->fetch();
echo json_encode($array);
</code>
```

Comment: this example is just awful in many aspects. But indeed "equal" to wrong way you were using old mysql ext. no error handling, no protection, bad performance.